# How avoid user run drop delta table from hive metastore

Tags: hive, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm having problems trying to run Data object privileges in databricks.

I have a configuration with a shared metastore between two azure databricks workspaces, to accomplish this I used another databricks workspace (master) and connect the other two workspaces to the hive metastore of this master, the image below shows this:

[image]

I followed this tutorial: https://cprosenjit.medium.com/sharing-databricks-hive-metastore-fb87727e2260 and it works fine, I can create a table inside dbcks workspace A and I can see the table data inside dbcks workspace B. Until here all good.

The problem is that a user inside A can drop a table created inside B, the drop command doesn't delete the table data because this is externalized to an azure datalake but it will delete the table definition in the shared metastore and this can become messy.

I tried to force governance following this article on azure [Data Object Privileges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/access-control/table-acls/object-privileges#requirements) and enabled table access control like this another [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/access-control/table-acls/table-acl#table-access-control) explains:

- Enable table access control for the Azure Databricks workspace.
  [image]
- Deny users access to clusters that are not enabled for table access control.
- Enable table access control and only allow Python and SQL commands in the cluster config
  [image]

After done this, I tried to run this command:

```
%sql 

GRANT SELECT ON DATABASE trusted_zone_af TO users
```

But I'm getting this error: **Table Access Control is not enabled on this cluster**

I restarted the cluster like 3 times, also, created another cluster and repeat the process, but I don't know what more to do.

Anyone can help me please,

If anyone have any suggestion in order to prevent drop commands to be executed on the metastore please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to run the notebook on a cluster which is **`not of High Concurrency mode`**. Table access control option is available only for [High Concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/access-control/table-acls/table-acl#--create-a-cluster-enabled-for-table-access-control) clusters.

**Example:** I have created two clusters as below, where **`ktestcluster`** is of High Concurrency mode and **`runtable`** is of standard mode. Now I have followed all the settings and prerequisites for using table access control.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, I am able to GRANT select as seen below from **`ktestcluster`**

[image]

But when I switch to **`runtable`**  cluster and try the same..bam! error

[image]

Further, to to prevent drop commands to be executed on the metastore,  Object ownership is represented here as the OWN privilege. Operation DROP TABLE  requires Privileges OWN on the table. So REVOKE OWN on the specific table for users so they cannot drop the table.

```
%sql 

REVOKE OWN ON TABLE sample4_csv TO `users`
```

If it returns an error that simply means they don't have the privilege to begin with. REVOKE can only work if there is already something assigned.